# Check if eventListener is running

Tags: lua, coronasdk, event-listener

How can i check if eventListener is running or not?

for example, i would like to achieve the following:

```
if (ball.y + vy  > 2) and EventListener-wallBounce-is-off then
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", wallBounce)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's not possible to check whether the event listener is active if you're checking for a collision of an object for a wall bounce why don't you use listener collision to detect if there will be any collision of object